# Plugin created using java code is not working

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, javacompiler

My in tension is to create a plugin at at the run time using java code.First a created executable jar using the `java.util.jar.JarOutputStream` and used `javax.tools.JavaCompiler` for compiling the classes. And I was able to execute the jar from command line properly.

Then I tried to create a pluign by including the plugin.xml file in the jar package and compiled the classes by using the above packages and plugin is created with out any errors.

But I was using an extension point for the plugin and it is not detecting while I am putting my plugin in the eclipse product.

Then I exported it by using eclispe export option and it is working properly for me. I unzipped both the jar created programtically and by using eclispe and the contents are same.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: If the contents are the same then they should both work or both not work. So there must be some difference in the contents.

Comment: Same in the sense the jar entries...Plugin.xml and Manifest files are same.But there are some differences in the .class files.But the source file I used for both is same.Is it something related to compilation issue?..